# How do I register more than 1 custom Elementor widget within my child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I recently followed this simple tutorial that allowed me to register and use my own custom Elementor widget on a WordPress site that I'm developing.

https://develowp.com/build-a-custom-elementor-widget/

What I can't figure out, however, is how to adapt this code so that I can register multiple different elementor widgets.  What's happening right now is that as soon as I try to register a 2nd custom Elementor widget -- the 2nd widget completely overrides my 1st widget (both within Elementor in the admin, as well as on the front end of the site.

Here are the few lines of code that I tried modifying in my "my-widgets.php" file (which I am referencing in my functions.php file, just like in the tutorial):

```
    protected function __construct() {      
        require_once('rpp_contact_bar.php');
        require_once('rpp_newsletter_sign_up_bar.php');
        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );
    }       

    public function register_widgets() {
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor\My_Widget_1() );
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor\My_Widget_2() );
    }
```

Note that my 2 widget PHP files (referenced in the code above) use the class names "My_Widget_1" and "My_Widget_2" to extend the "Widget_Base" class.

What am I missing here?  What is the proper way to register multiple different custom Elementor widgets within a child theme?

Thanks,
--- Yvan

Comment: Perhaps the `get_name()` method on both of your classes (`My_Widget_1` and `My_Widget_2`) returns the same name. You should change one of them, so each widget has a unique name. Though, you haven't provided the code of your classes, so I can't tell for sure if that's the case.

Comment: Aha!! You were definitely on to something there.  As it turned out, both of my widgets were returning the same name value as you suspected (each was returning "title-subtitle").  I modified the 2nd widget so that it returns the value of "title", .. which seemed to do the trick -- but I have no idea why.  What are some valid values that I can return for the get_name() method?  I tried just making one up, like "rpp-newsletter-signup-bar", but that didn't work, and I guess I just got lucky when I tried using "title".  Is there any documentation regarding this get_name() method, perhaps?

Comment: Happy to help! Btw, I just posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes (`My_Widget_1` and `My_Widget_2`, in your example) contain a `get_name()` method, which returns the same name for both of your widgets. You should change one of them so each name is unique.

> Each widget needs to have a few basic settings like a unique name that the widget will be identified by in the code […]

– ["Creating a New Widget"](https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/), Elementor Developers

---

It seems that widgets follow the same rules as function names in PHP (i.e. starting with a letter or underscore, followed by letters, numbers, or underscores). Though, I couldn't find anything mentioning that in the docs.

So, I think your `title-subtitle` wasn't working because of the hyphen (`-`).

Comment: Well .. the get_name() method in my first widget returns "title-subtitle", so I don't think it's choking on the hyphen.  I know that I can't just return any value that I want .. so I'm just wondering if there's some list of "allowed" values that I can return (I can't find anything in the docs about it either).  Still .. thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below code -

```
protected function __construct() {      
        require_once('rpp_contact_bar.php');
        require_once('rpp_newsletter_sign_up_bar.php');
        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this,'register_widgets' ] );
        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this,'register_widgets_1' ] );
    }       

    public function register_widgets() {
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor\My_Widget_1() );
    }

    public function register_widgets_1() {
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor\My_Widget_2() );
    }
```

Comment: Maulik - thank you for this, although you'll see in my comment above that I've already resolved this issue (thanks to the tip from over-engineer).  As it turned out, it was an issue with the get_name() methods in each widget both returning the same value -- which I've corrected.  I'm not quite sure how to "accept" his answer, however, since it was only a comment.  Can anyone here enlighten me, perhaps?